# Can I run an MP4 on my website without using a program on my computer?

Tags: html, embed, mp4

I have an MP4 file I want embeded on my website.  I do not want to rely on users having any software on their computer or not having the plugin or have extensions active.  How can I run this file automatically without local requirements.

Comment: You gonna need *something*. Something that can play videos, preferably. It won't work without anything at all. Have you looked whether the HTML5 `<video>` specification fits your needs?

Comment: Something like http://mediaelementjs.com/ will minimize the hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload it to youtube, convert it to .ogg and .webm to get a cross browser compatibily. Or use Flash.  Playing video on a website is not easy. By asking google you would have found [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp).

Comment: There does not appear to be an easy way to execute a movie file on the internet with another program also on the web other than using a utility like youtube or other online program.  I wanted to put a program on my site to run the video.  Just use an established internet accessable program.